# How to verify a wordpress user at a servlet?

Tags: java, php, wordpress, session, servlets

I'd like to embed an ajax application into a wordpress site. The ajax application will communicate with servlets running on tomcat. Now the servlets need a way to verify if a request originates from a user that is logged in to wordpress. How does this commonly get solved?

AFAIK, wordpress is stateless and does not use sessions, which makes me curious how a logged in user in wordpress can be tracked. 
The second problem is, how can a servlet request wordpress to verify if a given user is still logged in?

Any advice is welcome,
Thank you.

Comment: how do you conclude that Wordpress does not use sessions?

Comment: Various sources (for example http://bit.ly/yZoAKy, but a lot of other pages tell the same) on the net mention that wordpress aims to be stateless. Also, there's no session/uid table at the database. So I assume sessions are the wrong route to go.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can do is read the cookies. And that will work only if you are using the same domain (or subdomain and the cookies are valid for all subdomains). The session cookie might not give you sufficient information, however. You can't read a PHP session from a Java app, and generally, you can't mix two applications that way.

As a little workaround, you can check with javascript who is the currently logged user (by finding the username in the DOM), and send that with ajax, but that is not secure at all.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. My original idea was to store the sessionid in a javascript variable (this way the ajax app can easily access it) and transfer it with every call to the servlet. Then the servlet asks wordpress if the sessionid is still valid and performs or refuses the the call. (This workflow would be quite similar like CAS, just without the need of a CAS Server). The question is, is this implementable in wordpress? (Would be no problem doing it in drupal or joomla as both save the sessionid and userid in the database.)